# Does Ubuntu 22.04 support the libzip5 package?

Tags: 22.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04, I was previously using Ubuntu 20.04.  I has some software installed in the older OS version that relied on libzip5 but I can no longer install the package via `sudo apt install libzip5`.  Is there another way to install this package and if so, where can I download it/get it from a PPA etc.  Without this package, I get the following error for any programs that rely on it:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any information will be extremely helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the software that still depends on libzip5? There might be a way to make it work with libzip4 in Ubuntu 22.04. The package was temporarily renamed to libzip5 in Ubuntu 20.04 to circumvent some issue.

Comment: It is for Flycast-dojo.  Thank you so much for answering this!  In addition to the libzip5 package, we also need a dependency installed as well which I was able to find.  Here are the steps to installing the dependency:

Download the libssl1 package:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb

Then install it via the following command:
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb

I am now able to use my application in Ubuntu 22.04 thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it from the [Ubuntu 20.04 repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libzip5/download).

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libz/libzip/libzip5_1.5.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libzip5_1.5.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```